# CSS modules not working for react version 16.6.0

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I was trying to use CSS Modules in React.

Here my code of App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './index.css'

const App = () => {
    const REACT_VERSION = React.version;

  return (
    <div>
      Main app
      <div style={styles.test}>Green</div>
      <div>Yellow</div>
      <div>React version: {REACT_VERSION}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is my code of index.css

```
.test {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 34px;
  border: 34px;
}
```

Here is the output

[image]

I know that I have to modify

- webpack.config.dev.js
- webpack.config.prod.js

but when I read [this](https://medium.com/nulogy/how-to-use-css-modules-with-create-react-app-9e44bec2b5c2) article I could not find that code.

Comment: @Rob ok thank you very much for your clarification.

Comment: dont use dash(-) in style name

Answer (score 62):

I had this same problem and solved it by renaming my css file to:

```
myName.module.css
```

and also importing like this:

```
import styles from './myName.module.css'
```

There is no need to follow the steps of updating the webpack files any more.

Comment: Note: this is a webpack-in-Create React App convention. If you write your own webpack config for a custom React setup, no such convention exists and this wouldn't work.

Comment: Just confirming this solution works perfectly in react 16.12. Thanks!

Comment: Not working with React 17.0.1. The only way to make it work is Changing to UpperCase all the css classes in the css file. Doesn't matter if is camelCase or UpperCase the name of the file. It does not make any impact. What matters is all the css classes in UpperCase.

Answer (score 12):

in react 16.13 and  `react-scripts@2.0.0` and higher you don't need to eject your project.
Your CSS files must be named camelCase + .modules.css and import to your projects like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './app.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button className={styles.test}>Error Button</button>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

and in `app.module.css`

```
.test{
  color: blue;
}
```

if you eject projects, in `webpack.config.js` file, in css modules change like this:

```
   test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
```

Comment: Thanks, anyone else remember `camelCase` not **C**amelCase. Seems odd since the `App.js` uses a Capital at the start

Answer (score 10):

The person in other question was totally right but with a little mistake, without updating the config you can do it. Just put `.module` in front of your name of css file like that:

```
myName.module.css
```

Then call it :

```
import styles from './myName.module.css'
```

Working on React 16.6

Answer (score 4):

I think it will definitely help you out.
open config/webpack.config.js and find block like this.

```
        {
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders(
            {
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
            },
            'css-loader'
          ),
         sideEffects: true,
        },
```

and change that like this :

```
        {
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                ? shouldUseSourceMap
                : isEnvDevelopment,
            modules: {
              getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
            }

          }),
          sideEffects: true,
        },
```

Do same for cssModuleRegex block right after above block and restart your server and you'll get css modules enabled.

Comment: it's not work for header tag can you please guide what i miss it.

Answer (score 4):

`* as` fixed my problem.

```js
import * as headerStyles from './header.module.scss'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this work for you.

- My react version is 16.8.2 and after 16.2.0 you don't have ***config/webpack.config.dev.js*** or ***config/webpack.config.prod.js*** version on webpack.
- You only have **config/webpack.config.js** and **config/webpackDevServer.config.js** files after eject operation in react app.So to resolve this issue open **config/webpack.config.js** file and update these changes.***(See line:- 391 to 464)***

  ```
          {
        test: cssRegex,
        exclude: cssModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction
            ? shouldUseSourceMap
            : isEnvDevelopment,

          modules: true,
          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
        }),
        // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
        // containing package claims to have no side effects.
        // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
        // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
        sideEffects: true,
      },
      // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
      // using the extension .module.css
      {
        test: cssModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction
            ? shouldUseSourceMap
            : isEnvDevelopment,
          modules: true,
          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
        }),
      },
      // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
      // By default we support SASS Modules with the
      // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
      {
        test: sassRegex,
        exclude: sassModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders(
          {
            importLoaders: 2,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
              ? shouldUseSourceMap
              : isEnvDevelopment,
          modules: true,
          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ),
        // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
        // containing package claims to have no side effects.
        // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
        // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
        sideEffects: true,
      },
      // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
      // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
      {
        test: sassModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders(
          {
            importLoaders: 2,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
              ? shouldUseSourceMap
              : isEnvDevelopment,
            modules: true,
            getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ),
      },
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS files must be named like "*yourFileName.module.css*".
And import into your JS file like below:
import **yourVariableName** from "*./yourFileName.module.css*";

Works fine on React version:

```
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-dom": "^16.9.0",
"react-scripts": "3.1.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Checked with React 17.0.1**

This is what you need to do:

1. Rename your css file, from: 'index.css' to: 'index.module.css'. It doesn't matter the notation for the naming of that css file (now as a *.module.css file). It won't make any difference if is '*myFile.module.css*' or '*MyFile.module.css*'. The solution is not there precisely.
2. Import your *.module.css from your js file:

   import style from './CourseGoalList.module.css';
3. Access to your css clases with the usual CSS Modules syntax:

   ... className={style.NameOfTheCssClass}...
4. In the case you have css classes with dashes, you can do two things. Either remove the dashes renaming them to UpperCase or camelCase or you can access them like to a Map object (with key: value pairs). Even when you will be able to access/see those classes from your JS file (with the usual autocomplete code feature in your IDE), as camelCase classes,... they still **wont** work that way (with camelCase notation on your .js file and exactly as they are in the css file). It is **imperative** to either change the css classes name to UpperCase or camelCase (accessing with UpperCase or camelCase notation from the *.js file) or leave them as they are and then access them like if they were a Map object.

Example: You can do one of two things:

**Variant A:** It works perfectly

**JS File:**

```
import React from 'react';
import CourseGoalItem from '../CourseGoalItem/CourseGoalItem';
import style from './CourseGoalList.module.css';

const CourseGoalList = props => {
  return (
    <ul className={style.GoalList}>
      {props.items.map(goal => (
        <CourseGoalItem
          key={goal.id}
          id={goal.id}
          onDelete={props.onDeleteItem}
        >
          {goal.text}
        </CourseGoalItem>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default CourseGoalList;
```

**CSS File:**

```
.GoalList {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

OR:

**Variant B:** It works perfectly

**JS File:**

```
import React from 'react';
import CourseGoalItem from '../CourseGoalItem/CourseGoalItem';
import style from './CourseGoalList.module.css';

const CourseGoalList = props => {
  return (
    <ul className={style['goal-list']}>
      {props.items.map(goal => (
        <CourseGoalItem
          key={goal.id}
          id={goal.id}
          onDelete={props.onDeleteItem}
        >
          {goal.text}
        </CourseGoalItem>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default CourseGoalList;
```

**CSS File:**

```
.goal-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But this **WONT** work:

**Variant C:** It doesn't works (even if the css class is "*visible*" from your js file using a good IDE, like WebStorm for example)

**JS File:**

```
import React from 'react';
import CourseGoalItem from '../CourseGoalItem/CourseGoalItem';
import style from './CourseGoalList.module.css';

const CourseGoalList = props => {
  return (
    <ul className={style.goalList}>
      {props.items.map(goal => (
        <CourseGoalItem
          key={goal.id}
          id={goal.id}
          onDelete={props.onDeleteItem}
        >
          {goal.text}
        </CourseGoalItem>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default CourseGoalList;
```

**CSS File:**

```
.goal-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Case C did the job for me. WebStorm's intellisense converts kebab case to camel case which was causing the problem.

Comment: @Joel Same problem here too. This answer saved my time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you found solution or not but this worked for me. I was following a tutorial to use CSS module but tutor's react version was different from mine. he had react 16.0.0, and I have 16.7.0.  I don't have dev or prod version on webpack. I only have webpack.config.js. so what I did, I had a code on line 400

```
{
     test: cssRegex,  // cssRegex defined above as /\.css$/; 
     exclude: cssModuleRegex,
     use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,

          //this is the code tutor wrote.
         //================================================
          modules: true,
          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
          //================================================


     }),
     // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
     // containing package claims to have no side effects.
     // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
     // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
     sideEffects: true,
},
```

I hope it helps.

Note: the only thing I wrote is what I mentioned in block, everything else was already there.

Answer (score 1):

if ur using CSS class or id so no need to as a variable use import CSS.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import './index.css'

    const App = () => {
        const REACT_VERSION = React.version;

      return (
        <div >
          Main app
          <div className="test">Green</div>
          <div>Yellow</div>
          <div>React version: {REACT_VERSION}</div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default App;
```

or

```
import React from 'react';
const style ={
  background: black,
  color: white,
  fontSize: 34px,
  border: 34px
}

    const App = () => {
        const REACT_VERSION = React.version;

      return (
        <div >
          Main app
          <div style={style}>Green</div>
          <div>Yellow</div>
          <div>React version: {REACT_VERSION}</div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: your answer is not bad but it converts whole din into green thx anyways @asif vora :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to create the project in this way:

   ```
   create-react-app projectname --scripts-version 1.1.5
   ```
2. Apply:

   ```
   npm run eject
   ```
3. CSS-loader to `webpack.config.prod.js` and `webpack.config.dev.js` files. It is necessary to add the following settings for options. Otherwise, react CSS modules structure does not work.

   ```
   {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
          options: {
             importLoaders: 1,
             modules: true,
             localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Adding .module in the name of css files enables the css loader in the higher version of React. Post doing this, you can simple use ***className={styles.classname(from css file)}*** in the mail file. This will apply the particular class property to that HTML element.

At the top of the file Just Import
import styles from './mystyle.module.css'

It will work..

Answer (score 0):

Add class instead of style like

```
<div className="test">Green</div>
```

Comment: thx @Lalji Tadhani it is working. But my question is that I did not modify these config files and how comes that it is working? or maybe in the newer version we don't need to modify them?

Comment: @user2983359 it is done by react internally even in older version than 16.6

Comment: then why there are so many articles that you have modify these 2 config files?

Comment: That will reference the style in a static fashion and short-circuit the usage of css modules.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the React version as you know. The recent version requires you to name CSS and sass files as follows:

```
[name].moudle.css or [name].moudule.scss.
```

If renaming files this way is not working. 
you should enable it manual. 
if you did create your project with react-create-app and didn't eject it to have access to all your config files. do as follow :

```
npm run eject
```

it will create a config folder. inside that config file open your webpack.config files(there should be two)
you have to add this in your test: /.css$/ option :

```
modules: true,
localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
```

it should look like this

```
 test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        require.resolve('style-loader'),
                        {
                            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                            options: {
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                modules: true,
                                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                            },
                        },
```

do it in both webpack.config files

Note: do note tweak something else there unless you know what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Changing the css filename to something like "myfile.module.css" and them importing it "import styles from './myfile.module.css' solved my issue. Even though I don't know why I have to use module in my filename.

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to the question

Answer (score 0):

This needs latest react-scripts atleast greater than 4.0.0. So run `npm install --save react-scripts@latest` and try which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In the React file, the module stylesheet is imported using the import statement, and the imported styles are assigned to the style variable. The className attribute of the  element is then set to style.my_class, which applies the defined CSS styles to the corresponding element.

**CSS file:** *component_name.module.css*

```css
    .my_class {
       background-color: red;
    }
```

**REACT file:** *component_name.jsx*

```
    import style from "./component_name.module.css"

    const Component = () => {
       return (
           <div className={style.my_class}>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
       )
    }
```