# React Component Not Picking up CSS file

Tags: css, reactjs

I used the webpack create-react-app with npx. I have a component I saved in the src directory, header.css, and Header.js. It seems that the css file is not working as intended, it is not styling my component.  I have the following component structure.

**header.css**:

```
.header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: baseline;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    background-color: rgb(192,45,26);
    color: #fff;
}
```

**Header.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.css';


function Header() 
{
    
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>VACCINE</h1>
            </div>
        );
    
}

export default Header;
```

Any help would be appreciated, I followed the following thread but it didn't seem to work:

[CSS modules not working for react version 16.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062306/css-modules-not-working-for-react-version-16-6-0)

Comment: You're currently not using the css class. Did you mean `<div className="header">`?

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to html and css

Answer (score 3):

You've successfully imported the css file, which is step 1. Step 2 is actually using the styles found within. Just apply a class to your `div` header:

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.css';


function Header() 
{

    return (
        <div className="header">
            <h1>VACCINE</h1>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Header;
```